# Добавление блока в конец блока без его перезагрузки

Tags: javascript

Как на чистом JS, если это возможно, добавить блоки в конец блока по `id`, не перезагружая его?

Сейчас код выглядит таким образом:

```
function add_market_meta() {
    meta_block = document.getElementById('ShowMetaBox');
    var form = 'Market <input type="text" name="market_N' + i + '"><br/>';
    i++;
    document.getElementById('count_markets').value = i;
    meta_block.innerHTML += form;
};
```

Что, конечно, добавляет новый `input`, но перезагружает все добавленные до этого, из-за чего исчезают внесённые в них пользователем значения.

Как можно решить задачу иначе? И очень не хочется тащить jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот решение:

```js
var i = 0;

function add_market_meta(){
    var meta_block = document.getElementById('ShowMetaBox'), fragment, input;
    
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Market "));
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = "market_N" + i;
    fragment.appendChild(input);
    fragment.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    
    i++;
    document.getElementById('count_markets').value = i;
    meta_block.appendChild(fragment);
};
```

```html
<div id="ShowMetaBox"></div>
<input id="count_markets" type="button" onclick="add_market_meta()" value="0" />
```

Здесь используется [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) чтобы сначала создать кусок DOM, а затем его добавить сразу в документ. Работает как `innerHTML =+ '...'` но не перезаписывает старый кусок DOM

Comment: Ну и при желании (и небольшом количестве добавляемых элементов) `appendChild` можно делать сразу к `meta_block`, не создавая `fragment`.

Comment: @Regent согласен, да. В своём ответе я как бы переделал innerHTML: изменения в DOM происходят сразу, а не по частям.

Comment: @АндрейМиндубаев Спасибо большое, разобрался! мне почему-то казалось, что `appendChild` это функция jQuery. Возможно я перепутал с `append`